# How do you configure draggableviews permissions?

Tags: views

How can I configure draggableviews permissions so that I can sort and save my gallery (as in photo gallery) but no other visitor can?
I want to be the only one with permission to sort and save my display. As of now, I can sort and save other users' displays.
Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Do you mean that many users can create galleries and you only want users to edit their own?

Comment: All users can create and edit their own galleries. They cannot edit and delete pictures from other users' galleries and this is normal. What is not normal is that they can sort (or rearrange the sorting order) of other users' galleries. Only the gallery owner should be able to edit, delete and sort pictures on his own gallery..

Comment: Are the galleries a node with many images or collection of nodes? I think you need to find a way to only display a draggable view if the user is the author. You can still use the weighting in views that aren't draggable I believe. Hard to answer without more specifics.

Comment: Galleries are nodes holding a collection of nodes. Yes, finding a way to only display a draggable view when the user is the author is what I am trying to do. But users do not have permission to edit views.